# postfix/dovecot: deliver per-user unlimited aliases to individual folders

Tags: email, imap, smtp, postfix, dovecot

## Context

On a Debian server hosting a small-traffic domain, a decent e-mail setup runs postfix as SMTP server and dovecot as IMAP.

Postfix configuration includes this:

```
recipient_delimiter = _
```

which causes addresses liks `user_anyword@domain` to be delivered to folder INBOX of `user@domain`. So far, so good.

## Wish : `user_anyword@domain` to folder `anyword`

We wish that mail addressed to `user_anyword@domain` be delivered to folder `anyword` of user `user@domain`.

## Search before you post

These pages are probably highly relevant:

- http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA
- http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix
- http://wiki.dovecot.org/LMTP

## Possible approach

It can probably be achieved based on http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix and http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter . The idea would be to leverage the configuration between `postfix` and `dovecot-lda` and add a `-m` parameter to tell the destination folder:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT" -m "${recipient_delimiter}${extension}"
```

Those `dovecot-lda` options would probably be useful:

```
lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
```

I might probably try that soon.  Any comment? Can you offer variants or different solutions?

Comment: Have you looked at Sieve? I think it's the recommended way for sorting delivery into folders for Dovecot, and there is an example config that seems to do what you want. Maybe using subaddress, fileinto, variable options as shown at http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Plus_Addressed_mail_filtering .

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd recommend:

1. Use [LMTP to send from postfix to dovecot](https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP)
2. At it says at the bottom of the [LMTP page](https://wiki.dovecot.org/LMTP), set

   ```
   lmtp_save_to_detail_mailbox = yes
   recipient_delimiter = _
   ```